Operator Precedence in JS between ? and ||

In the image above, I get the value some new value as the output. Could somebody explain me why that is happening? I thought I would get test value as the output but it doesn't seems to be the case. Thanks in advance

Please post code as text in the question, even better would be a snippet that we could all run directly from the question.

You essentially answered the question in the title... operator precedence.  For your operators, the order is first >, then ||, then ?:.

See the docs on operator precedence. Logical || has higher precedence than ternary expression so the line is effectively (variable?.first || (1 > 5)) ? "some new value" : "some other new value". Sounds like you wanted variable?.first || (1 > 5  ? "some new value" : "some other new value") instead though.

?. is a different operator than ? :

The presence of first on the variable object is checked first. Since it is true. the expression passes and "new value" is assigned. The condition will short-circuit, and the 1 > 5 condition will not be need to be checked.
Note: If the value of first was undefined or falsy, then the 1 > 5 expression would be checked. It would result in false, so the "other value" would be assigned.


const variable = { first: "test value" }; // variable.first is present

const newVal = (variable?.first || (1 > 5)) ? "new value" : "other value";
//                      ^ true  OR  ^ false = ^ true value

console.log(newVal); // "new value"




Please don't post answers on obviously off topic/bad questions! See: Should one advise on off topic questions?
